# Projection misalignment google geojson vs d3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, d3.js, geojson

For a given geoJSON file, which in this case is the county boundaries for Illinois, I'm overlapping the [google.maps.Data()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data) layer and [D3.geo.path()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths) with [mercator projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-mercator), and [I notice a displacement between both projections](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/ba21cbada391e053d899).

The google data layer (in red) is an object which displays in the same canvas as any google overlay (polygons, markers, polylines, etc) while the D3.geo.path() (in blue) shows up in an SVG container I overlap on top of the google container.

[image: Difference between projections]

As you can see, the westernmost counties show the google borderline to the left of the D3 line, while towards the east, the D3 is the one displaced to the left.

At first I thought I was mis-centering the SVG container, but this example shows that the displacement is not uniform, so I can't fix it playing with SVG transform matrix.

This fenomena happens to any geoJSON, no matter the zoom or the place of the world I try with. Now, this is strange, because if d3.geo.mercator() was mistranslating coords to pixels, the miscalculation wouldn't be uniform. It isn't an approximation issue either, because it doesn't vary with zoom.

Is this just a minor issue with different projection engines? I wouldn't expect google, d3, leaflet and openlayers translating a coordinate pair to the exact same pixel, but I don't want to ignore this one for I might be doing somethign wrong.

Any ideas would be appreciated. @mbostock, I summon thee.

EDIT: It took me a lot to come out with a self-contained example, but it helped me understand better what was happening under the hood.

Please see http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/ba21cbada391e053d899

Comment: Could be anything from faulty GeoJSON to something transforming the container. Can't really tell you more without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks. I added a self-contained example in bl.ocks.org. I hope my question doesn't get closed.

Comment: Hmm, how are you computing the translation and zoom of the D3 part of the map?

Comment: I took that part out of the example because it didn't affect the initial projection, but what I do is add a zoom behavior with a callback function that calculates the difference in coordinates and zoom related to the original center/zoom, and then applies the proper translate attribute for the g group. The SVG is appended on the overlayMouseTarget pane of an OverlayView to avoid it interferring with map dragging and zooming.

Comment: What I'm aiming at is whether the scale could be off very slightly, causing the shift you're seeing.

Comment: I get your point. I was passing D3 a scale of ```40.5 * 2^zoom``` but now I can't find where did that 40.5 came from. I'm getting slighly better results with a constant of 40.704